# Using custom title, content and image to share link on facebook not working

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, share, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I'm using the Facebook head tags to generate specific title, description and images when they want to share a link in their Facebook page, it looks like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="thumbnail_image" />
```

But if I try to share my link it doesn't pick them up, it just shows the default info. If I look in the source code the meta tags are formatted correctly so I'm not sure what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the Facebook Debugger to see what's wrong with your page:
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: That's strange it says I should explicitly provide the title, description and other values but if you look at the source code they're there, this is the url I'm testing: http://mrgreen.medialounge-dev.co.uk/properties/100478000046

Comment: Mm I see the problem is that they're trying to pull the metadata from http://mrgreen.medialounge-dev.co.uk/properties/ not http://mrgreen.medialounge-dev.co.uk/properties/100478000046 not sure why..

Comment: Oh the problem's that I'm using a canonical url to that link, I removed it and it's working fine now thanks!